# Drupal Commerce variations missing when creating content

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce

I have downloaded and installed the Commerce module.

**Note 1:**
I have a product which is made up of 2 changeable parameters e.g. say size and colour... depending upon the size and colour chosen the user will be presented with a price... Currently, this leads to a potential 18 combinations all with unique prices.

**Note 2:**
I have created a product content type e.g. T shirt

**Note 3:**
I have created 18 products with unique SKU codes for each of the possible combinations and associated prices (of the product type created in Note 2)

[image]

**Note 4:**
I have created a standard content type (under structure - which is intended to be used to show the product as a piece of content e.g. admin>structure>content type).  The field holding the product is of type "Product Reference" and the product reference fields, field setting is set to unlimited

[image]

**Note 5:**
The content type is configured to allow the user to select the 18 different variants (created in Note 3) of the product type created in note 2.

**Note 6:**
The content node of the type created in Note 4 works by showing the product and changes the price depending upon what the user selects from the two options e.g. size and colour

**The issue:**
In the content type created in Note 4 (e.g. the content node) it only shows the last 10 products created (of the product type created in Note 2) rather than showing the required 18 products... how do you get to see the other 8 product variations so that they can be selected and show up in the content node in order that those combinations may be selected?

[image]

Anyone else experience this issue?  And found a solution to it?

It looks like the widget in the content creation gui only lists up to 10 items - so I'm only seeing the last 10 items created but how to I also see the addition 8 items created.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Commerce 1.14. This is a well-known issue with an artificial options list introduced in prior versions. While you're at it, make sure you're running the latest version of Drupal core and taken care of any security releases, too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this ... I am using the Commerce module as provided by https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce it has version 7.x-1.14 released on the 16th Nov 2017 and using Drupal core 7.56

Comment: Your input did raise an interesting point regarding using the latest version of commerce and the fact that I had seen this https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference/issues/2185019#comment-12308833 post which seem to outline the problem I was experiencing.  It seemed to suggest they had identified the issue - i then realised the drupal.org/project/commerce site had a dev version which was the patched version... installing it resolved the issue i was experiencing.  Thanks for your input Ryan Szrama.